# Ошибка в api openweather

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не получается взаимодействовать с api openweather, вставляю значения широты и долготы, пишет неправильная широта. При этом если написать широту и долготу цифрами, все работает, широта и долгота тоже определяется верно, ниже приложу скрин.

```js
ymaps.ready(locationPub);

function locationPub() {
  var geolocation = ymaps.geolocation,
    coords = [geolocation.latitude, geolocation.longitude];
  let latt = [geolocation.latitude]
  let lonl = [geolocation.longitude]
  fetch("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={latt}&lon={lonl}&appid=2bd27f8ac9131b3542b76fd4f604fd73")
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp.json()
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    })
  console.log(latt)
  console.log(lonl)

}
```

Может, кто нибудь подскажет что я не так делаю?

Comment: Не двойные кавычки, а бэктики (там где клавиша тильды) надо использовать.

Comment: fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={latt}&lon={lonl}&appid=2bd27f8ac9131b3542b76fd4f604fd73`) Сделал так, ничего не изменилось(

Comment: Я не говорил совсем убрать кавычки, а заменить на бэктики. Вы разницу улавливаете?

Comment: скопировалось не так, прошу прощения, все получилось, спасибо вам огромное!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в двойных кавычках,нужно было использовать "бэктики"(``)
Ниже прикреплю результат[image: введите сюда описание изображения]